Nette Tester deletes my test after failure and forbids its recreation in the same directory
Nette Tester tells me the tests went fine, even though I know they couldn't have
Terminal saying test is OK
and then deletes the test that failed and i can't create it back in that folder anymore
Pop-up window saying "unable to write at the location"
After restarting my PC, I can create the test again but if it fails, I'm back here
It didn't happen, when I used Tester in school, so maybe it has something to do with my settings?
this is the test code, just to be sure
<?php

    use Tester\Assert;
    require "bootstrap.php";
    require "src/classes.php";


    class ArticleTest extends Tester\TestCase
    {

        public function setUp()
        {
            # Příprava
        }

        public function tearDown()
        {
            # Úklid
        }

        public function getTitleLoopArgs()
        {   
            return [
                ["Šumavské slatě", 1],
                ["Materhorn v noci", 2],
                ["Šumava slatě II", 3]
            ];
        }


        /**
            * @dataProvider getTitleLoopArgs
        */

        public function testGetTitle($precondition,$id)
        {
            $clanek = new Article($id);
            Assert::same($precondition,$clanek->getTitle());
        }

        public function getProfileImgLoopArgs()
        {
            return [
                ["uploadImages/slateSumava.jpg", 1],
                ["uploadImages/Matterhorn.jpg", 2],
                ["uploadImages/slateSumava.jpg", 3]
            ];
        }

        /**
            * @dataProvider getProfileImgLoopArgs
        */

        public function testGetProfileImg($precondition,$id)
        {
            $clanek = new Article($id);
            Assert::same($precondition,$clanek->getProfileImg());
        }


        public function getAuthorLoopArgs()
        {
            return [
                ["Karel Novák", 1],
                ["Jana Malá", 2],
                ["Karel Novák", 3]
            ];
        }

        /**
            * @dataProvider getAuthorLoopArgs
        */

        public function testGetAuthor($precondition,$id)
        {
            $clanek = new Article($id);
            Assert::same($precondition,$clanek->getAuthor());
        }

    }   

    (new ArticleTest)->run();
?>

I tried restarting my PC, which only helped so I could create the test again.
I also tried creating the test in a different location, but it also happened again, so now I cannot create the test in more locations.
